# Filling reports from json using JasperReports

Tags: java, json, jasper-reports, datasource

I'm beginner with JasperReports ( first try ) so,
I set up my netbeans, and my first try using data from database was successful. But now I just want to create my report from json data using Jasper Reports in Netbeans And I think it's not like getting data from Database.

By the way I tried to edit my xml file and add this :

```
<textField>
            <reportElement x="0" y="31" width="555" height="20" uuid="9678a129-61e8-4034-ab8e-739ee5723c87"/>
            <textElement textAlignment="Right">
                <font size="12" isBold="true"/>
            </textElement>
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{nom}]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
```

But it gives me null in report.

Here is what I did in java side :

```
Map parametersMap = new HashMap();
parametersMap.put("name", json.getString("Name"));
parametersMap.put("start", json.getString("Start"));
parametersMap.put("end", json.getString("end"));
String report = "C:\\My\\Path\\toReport\\report1.jrxml";
JasperReport Jasp = JasperCompileManager.compileReport(report);
JasperPrint JASP_PRINT = JasperFillManager.fillReport(Jasp,parametersMap);
JasperViewer.viewReport(JASP_PRINT);
```

UPDATED:

Here is my Java code

```
public void start(Future<Void> startFuture){

 String fileJSON = "C:\\Users\\PathToMyFile\\data.txt";
     String file =  "/Test1/:name";
    Router router = Router.router(vertx);
       router.route(file).handler(routingContext -> {
        HttpServerResponse response = routingContext.response();
        response.setChunked(true);
        routingContext.vertx().setTimer(1000, tid -> routingContext.response().end());
    });
    vertx.createHttpServer()
            .requestHandler(router::accept)
            .listen(8089, "localhost", res -> {
                if (res.succeeded())
                    startFuture.complete();
                else
                    startFuture.fail(res.cause());
            });

    vertx.fileSystem().readFile(fileJSON, (AsyncResult<Buffer> result) -> {
        if (result.succeeded()) {                
                                JsonObject json = result.result().toJsonObject();
                             try{
                                Map parametersMap = new HashMap();  
                                parametersMap.put("name",json.getString("name"));
                                parametersMap.put("start",json.getString("start"));
                                parametersMap.put("end",json.getString("end"));
                                String report = "C:\\Users\\pathToMyPackage\\report1.jrxml";
                                JasperReport Jasp = JasperCompileManager.compileReport(report);
                                JasperPrint JASP_PRINT = JasperFillManager.fillReport(Jasp,parametersMap);
                                JasperViewer.viewReport(JASP_PRINT);
```

And for my JRXML file :

```
<property name="ireport.zoom" value="1.0"/>
<property name="ireport.x" value="0"/>
<property name="ireport.y" value="0"/>
<queryString language="json">
    <![CDATA[]]>
</queryString>
<field name="nom" class="java.lang.String">
    <fieldDescription><![CDATA[name]]></fieldDescription>
</field>
<field name="dateDebut" class="java.lang.String">
    <fieldDescription><![CDATA[start]]></fieldDescription>
</field>
<background>
    <band splitType="Stretch"/>
</background>
<detail>
    <band height="125" splitType="Stretch">
        <textField>
            <reportElement x="100" y="0" width="100" height="30" uuid="02b279da-3795-4655-8571-5a36a3ef378c"/>
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{name}]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
        <staticText>
            <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="100" height="30" uuid="671e61ad-8d8f-48cb-969f-78c05a516398"/>
            <text><![CDATA[name]]></text>
        </staticText>
        <textField>
            <reportElement x="100" y="30" width="100" height="30" uuid="9d53f46f-a252-48b3-9213-8c3092c29f49"/>
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{start}]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
        <staticText>
            <reportElement x="0" y="30" width="100" height="30" uuid="3b49affb-685a-4df2-a872-c0e6fdcab94b"/>
            <text><![CDATA[start]]></text>
        </staticText>
    </band>
</detail>
```

And my JSON file :

```
{
"Name": "Test",
"Start": "16-06-2015",
"End":"16-06-2019"
 }
```

Comment: The sample of using: [JSON Data Source Overview](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/sample.reference/jsondatasource/index.html#jsondatasource)

Comment: I have posted a duplicate that show how to pass the json data source to report, basically you don't pass through parameter put as datasource see the duplicate (and if you solved it you accept duplicate)

Comment: Thank you Alex for the example but I still have some problems with

Comment: Petter I use vertx So I had to read from buffer and convert to Json file, I can see from the Jasper Docs they implement fill method without 3th argument ( fillReport(java.io.InputStream inputStream, java.util.Map<java.lang.String,java.lang.Object> parameters) ) 
I tried to create Report from your XML file by using my java code, but it gives me null, null, null

Comment: @zackzulg You should post the full sample to check: simple *json*, simple *jrxml*, simple *Java* code to generate report.

Comment: @zackzulg You should also add the json. Please, add this info to your question (original post)

Comment: @zackzulg You forgot to pass json to the report

Comment: @AlexK Yes I did, in these lines :
vertx.fileSystem().readFile(fileJSON, (AsyncResult<Buffer> result) -> {
        if (result.succeeded()) {                
                                JsonObject json = result.result().toJsonObject();
I verified if my map is filled by printing parametersMap.

Comment: @zackzulg I have updated the answer... let me know...

Comment: @AlexK I tried to create simple project, I used simple String but it stills doesn't work, I changed $F{name} to $P but it still doesn't work : here is my code :

Comment: public void printPDF(){String fileJSON = "{name: 'Stackoverflow', start: '15-06-2014', end: '02-09-2018'}"; InputStream iostream = new ByteArrayInputStream(fileJSON.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
try{JsonDataSource ds = new JsonDataSource(iostream);Map parametersMap = new HashMap(); String report = "C:\\Users\\paths\\report2.jrxml";JasperReport Jasp = JasperCompileManager.compileReport(report); JasperPrint JASP_PRINT=JasperFillManager.fillReport(Jasp,parametersMap,ds);JasperViewer.viewReport(JASP_PRINT);JasperExportManager.exportReportToPdfFile(JASP_PRINT, "C:\\Users\\Paths\\report2.pdf");

Comment: It seems it's related with Vertx beceause when I use it simple it works, but when I add my code to vertx code it generates null.

Comment: Problem solved, in my main method i was calling another class instead of my class. Thank you for help @AlexK

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to pass the data as a **datasource**, in json this is done by passing the stream through the parameter map (since you are using vertex, get the json in String format and then pass it as a stream).

**Example**

```
InputStream iostream = new ByteArrayInputStream(jsonString.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
parametersMap.put(JsonQueryExecuterFactory.JSON_INPUT_STREAM, iostream);
```

Then you can define the fields related to your json and json (xpath) query