# How to add a json array to a table using java so that I can pass cookies?

Tags: java, json, jasper-reports

I have json object like this

```
{
  "data":[
    {
       "no":1,
       "name" : "yuda",
       "address" : "surabaya"
    },
    {
        "no":2,
        "name":"adi",
        "address":"jakarta"
    }
  ],
  "comp_name":"TEST CORP",
  "title":"Company employee",
  "status":"success"
}
```

I serve that json with http rest API and I want to create report with jasper report and I have success if I pass it as an url `JsonQueryExecuterFactory.JSON_SOURCE`.

[image]

[image]

My problem is that I can't include session cookie in `JSON_SOURCE`, the solution I'm trying is to create a http request in java code and then include it with `JsonQueryExecuterFactory.JSON_INPUT_STREAM`, but it's not working, it just shows blank page. Even though I update parameter from `$P{net.sf.jasperreports.json.source}` to `$P{JSON_INPUT_STREAM}` it doesn't work.

Comment: Have you tried something like this? https://stackoverflow.com/a/36455240/5292302, it's unclear how you are currently trying to pass the datasource, try to create a [mcve]

Comment: @PetterFriberg I already read your answer on that question, it's worked if the json just standart json object, in my case, there is json array inside "data" key, and i need to put the json array inside the table.

Comment: ok check this on how you can create a `subDataSource` for your table from the main datasource https://stackoverflow.com/a/39401536/5292302

Comment: If you're not tied to a specific version of JasperReports, all your issues could be easily solved with latest(6.3.1) version: with [header properties](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/config.reference.html#net.sf.jasperreports.http.data.header) you could set a cookie header for your URL; with [JSONQL](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/sample.reference/jsonqldatasource/index.html) you could access the nested JSON arrays without having to create additional dataSets.

Comment: @Narcis please give me little example about **header properties**, i don't know how to use it.

Comment: @PetterFriberg if i put subreport on main report, the report not show, but if i remove the subreport, the report show

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> This is a full example of loading your json from a http request via java (you can add headers as you like), using a subreport to pass the `data` node as a [**`subDataSource`**](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/api/net/sf/jasperreports/engine/data/JsonDataSource.html#subDataSource())

**Example URL:** http://www.jdd.it/so/jsonTest.json <sup>*Your json is available on this url</sup>

## Main report (jsonMain.jrxml)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="JsonMain" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" columnWidth="555" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20" uuid="15289120-bdf0-4edd-905c-647999c3c0cc">
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.data.defaultdataadapter" value="json"/>
    <parameter name="SUBREPORT_DIR" class="java.lang.String" isForPrompting="false">
        <defaultValueExpression><![CDATA["C:\\jdd\\..path..to..subreport\\"]]></defaultValueExpression>
    </parameter>
    <queryString language="JSON">
        <![CDATA[]]>
    </queryString>
    <field name="comp_name" class="java.lang.String">
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[comp_name]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <field name="title" class="java.lang.String">
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[title]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <field name="status" class="java.lang.String">
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[status]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <detail>
        <band height="40">
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="115" height="20" uuid="023be3f7-66fc-4718-9ca3-220c16ddc97a"/>
                <textElement verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font size="14" isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Company name:]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="115" y="0" width="103" height="20" uuid="15aadf03-03a1-4c05-8bf9-cdf7db09153c"/>
                <textElement verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font size="14" isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{comp_name}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <subreport>
                <reportElement x="0" y="20" width="555" height="20" uuid="c8251ce1-5de4-476f-a4cc-89717d422cc7"/>
                <dataSourceExpression><![CDATA[((net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JsonDataSource)$P{REPORT_DATA_SOURCE}).subDataSource("data")]]></dataSourceExpression>
                <subreportExpression><![CDATA[$P{SUBREPORT_DIR} + "jsonMain_subreport.jasper"]]></subreportExpression>
            </subreport>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="218" y="0" width="39" height="20" uuid="4c8d8333-117a-4447-98ac-bfebbd28776a"/>
                <textElement verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font size="14" isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Title:]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="257" y="0" width="154" height="20" uuid="0f266993-1bf3-41cf-8db6-c8b5aaccef74"/>
                <textElement verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font size="14" isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{title}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="411" y="0" width="51" height="20" uuid="9afd4de9-5155-43a6-ae63-337bb77deac8"/>
                <textElement verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font size="14" isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Status:]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="462" y="0" width="93" height="20" uuid="6e8ab3b0-c8eb-40f4-ade8-9dd60e34a721"/>
                <textElement verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font size="14" isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{status}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </band>
    </detail>
</jasperReport>
```

> The key is to `subDataSource` the `data` node `((net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JsonDataSource)$P{REPORT_DATA_SOURCE}).subDataSource("data")`
> and pass this to subreport

## Subreport (jsonMain_subreport.jrxml)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="jsonMain_subreport" language="java" pageWidth="555" pageHeight="802" columnWidth="555" leftMargin="0" rightMargin="0" topMargin="0" bottomMargin="0" uuid="9c681432-4547-4fd8-91c1-5634ca368da6">
    <field name="no" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="name" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="address" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <columnHeader>
        <band height="20" splitType="Stretch">
            <staticText>
                <reportElement mode="Opaque" x="0" y="0" width="100" height="20" backcolor="#CCCCCC" uuid="3dbc394e-6a5a-45d2-8d53-c9880f3974e7"/>
                <box leftPadding="2" rightPadding="2">
                    <pen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                    <topPen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                    <rightPen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                </box>
                <textElement verticalAlignment="Middle"/>
                <text><![CDATA[No]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement mode="Opaque" x="100" y="0" width="167" height="20" backcolor="#CCCCCC" uuid="2c40967a-42d5-439e-a1c3-5d41fd50f906"/>
                <box leftPadding="2" rightPadding="2">
                    <pen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                    <topPen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                    <rightPen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                </box>
                <textElement verticalAlignment="Middle"/>
                <text><![CDATA[Name]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement mode="Opaque" x="267" y="0" width="288" height="20" backcolor="#CCCCCC" uuid="0d72063d-6354-4e8d-9f89-52d00d100d3e"/>
                <box leftPadding="2" rightPadding="2">
                    <pen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                    <topPen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                    <rightPen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                </box>
                <textElement verticalAlignment="Middle"/>
                <text><![CDATA[Address]]></text>
            </staticText>
        </band>
    </columnHeader>
    <detail>
        <band height="20" splitType="Stretch">
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="100" height="20" uuid="e9cc4829-5e9a-4747-a594-489b6230713c"/>
                <box leftPadding="2" rightPadding="2">
                    <pen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                    <topPen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                    <rightPen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                </box>
                <textElement verticalAlignment="Middle"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{no}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="100" y="0" width="167" height="20" uuid="1c02f144-1c6c-4704-9bfb-13ac39007841"/>
                <box leftPadding="2" rightPadding="2">
                    <pen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                    <topPen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                    <rightPen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                </box>
                <textElement verticalAlignment="Middle"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{name}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="267" y="0" width="288" height="20" uuid="e0b9aff3-c8e3-4895-90a2-339ffb7c856f"/>
                <box leftPadding="2" rightPadding="2">
                    <pen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                    <topPen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                    <rightPen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                </box>
                <textElement verticalAlignment="Middle"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{address}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </band>
    </detail>
</jasperReport>
```

> Nothing special in this report, the fields corresponds to the fields in your `data` node, remember to compile subreport to `.jasper` before running java code, since `.jasper` is indicated in main report.

## Java code

```
//Get our main report
JasperReport report = JasperCompileManager.compileReport("jsonMain.jrxml");
    
//Open url connection
URLConnection urlConn = new URL("http://www.jdd.it/so/jsonTest.json").openConnection();
//set some cookies
urlConn.setRequestProperty("Cookie", "cookie1=hello; cookie2=world");
    
//Get the stream
try (InputStream is =urlConn.getInputStream()) {
    Map<String, Object> parametersMap = new HashMap<>();
    //Pass to parameter map
    parametersMap.put(JsonQueryExecuterFactory.JSON_INPUT_STREAM, is);
    //Fill report
    JasperPrint jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(report, parametersMap);
    //Export to pdf
    JRPdfExporter exporter = new JRPdfExporter();
    exporter.setExporterInput(new SimpleExporterInput(jasperPrint));
    exporter.setExporterOutput(new SimpleOutputStreamExporterOutput("json.pdf"));
    SimplePdfExporterConfiguration configuration = new SimplePdfExporterConfiguration();
    configuration.setMetadataAuthor("Me");
    exporter.setConfiguration(configuration);
    exporter.exportReport();
}
```

## Result

[image: Output]

Comment: I think you already answer my question from the comment before, I am write a wrong code in subreport, I use **language="groovy"** in subreport, i should replace groovy with java.

Comment: You can use groovy also in report (you just need the libraries in classpath)

Comment: if the language value is groovy, the report not shown, then i replace it with java, everything going perfect like what i want.

Comment: Hi Petter, i've got another problem about subreport, if i run jar file with command line, my report not shown because can't find subreport file, but if i run it with netbeans everything going well. I am passing my subreport directory like this `SUBREPORT_DIR=file:/E:/test/target/test-1.0.jar!/reports/`

Comment: @yuda inside a jar?, I normally keep them outside and pass values like `c:\\dir\\subreports`, hence no file: and no subreport inside jars. If you like to keep'em inside jar, maybe it's better to pass an inputstream to each subreport as a parameter

Comment: Probably something like this `getClass().getResource("/reports/mySubreport.jasper").openStream()` in subreport expression will work also (class is `java.io.InputStream`)

Comment: where i put `getClass().getResource("/reports/mySubreport.jasper").openSt‌​ream()` in my project...? if i put it in java code i must passing it as parameter, i am already do that but the report not shows. if i press **compile report** button, i got an error `Unable to locate the subreport with expression: "$P{subreport1}"`

Comment: No in the subreport expression (the jar needs to be in classpath if from IDE), hence inside jrxml (you could also pass it as in inputstream or directly a jasper report from java as a parameter.

Comment: OK, I am understand now, my last question. if i use `InputStream` as parameter, there is popup shows while i click preview button. how to use default adapter (`json url api`) i choose as value of parameter `InputStream`.

Comment: @Yuda, on the parameter also from Studio or iReport, dis-check show as prompt and add a default expression instead.

Answer (score 5):

Here is the way to do it in newer JasperReports version 6.3.1 with the http properties and JSONQL:

The JRXML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="JsonHttpDataAdapterReport" columnCount="3" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" columnWidth="171" leftMargin="40" rightMargin="40" topMargin="50" bottomMargin="50" uuid="b85a2cf8-dd0c-4a31-804c-e7b217f9b42b">
    <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.data.adapter" value="JsonHttpDataAdapter.xml"/>
    <parameter name="CookieParam" class="java.lang.String" evaluationTime="Early">
        <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.http.data.header" value="Cookie"/>
        <defaultValueExpression><![CDATA["name1=val1;name2=val2"]]></defaultValueExpression>
    </parameter>
    <queryString language="jsonql">
        <![CDATA[data.*]]>
    </queryString>
    <field name="CompanyName" class="java.lang.String">
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[$.comp_name]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <field name="Title" class="java.lang.String">
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[$.title]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <field name="Number" class="java.lang.String">
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[no]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <field name="Name" class="java.lang.String">
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[name]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <field name="Address" class="java.lang.String">
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[address]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <background>
        <band splitType="Stretch"/>
    </background>
    <title>
        <band height="79" splitType="Stretch">
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="280" height="30" uuid="6333da35-2a4b-4373-9838-2d9e71981516"/>
                <textElement>
                    <font size="20"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{CompanyName}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </band>
    </title>
    <pageHeader>
        <band height="30" splitType="Stretch">
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="300" height="30" uuid="4062fecd-290c-4790-8f92-868d4c58f054"/>
                <textElement>
                    <font size="16"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{Title}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </band>
    </pageHeader>
    <columnHeader>
        <band height="31" splitType="Stretch">
            <staticText>
                <reportElement mode="Opaque" x="0" y="0" width="80" height="30" backcolor="#A7E9FA" uuid="b66244aa-5ae0-4e24-9b4f-aafd7f5883cc"/>
                <box topPadding="5" leftPadding="10" bottomPadding="0" rightPadding="0"/>
                <textElement>
                    <font isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Number]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement mode="Opaque" x="80" y="0" width="185" height="30" backcolor="#A7E9FA" uuid="965b8d2b-2baf-4842-be30-430ae395a8aa"/>
                <box topPadding="5" leftPadding="10" bottomPadding="0" rightPadding="0"/>
                <textElement>
                    <font isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Name]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement mode="Opaque" x="265" y="0" width="255" height="30" backcolor="#A7E9FA" uuid="f56fe462-a90f-4228-a243-3222552f7e45"/>
                <box topPadding="5" leftPadding="10" bottomPadding="0" rightPadding="0"/>
                <textElement>
                    <font isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Address]]></text>
            </staticText>
        </band>
    </columnHeader>
    <detail>
        <band height="30" splitType="Stretch">
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="80" height="30" uuid="6b8a6731-19d4-44ee-b41f-c6977729d334"/>
                <box topPadding="5" leftPadding="10"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{Number}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="80" y="0" width="185" height="30" uuid="6e51e1eb-ff0e-4e2f-aa05-056060901aff"/>
                <box topPadding="5" leftPadding="10"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{Name}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="265" y="0" width="255" height="30" uuid="b79f1a8e-627f-4952-b5eb-632d5db771eb"/>
                <box topPadding="5" leftPadding="10"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{Address}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </band>
    </detail>
</jasperReport>
```

The JsonHttpDataAdapter.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<jsonDataAdapter class="net.sf.jasperreports.data.json.JsonDataAdapterImpl">
    <name>JSON Http Data Adapter</name>
    <dataFile xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
            xsi:type="httpDataLocation">
        <method>GET</method>
        <url>http://domaindotsomething/data.json</url>
    </dataFile>
    <language>jsonql</language>
    <useConnection>true</useConnection>
    <timeZone xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:java="http://java.sun.com"
              xsi:type="java:java.lang.String">Europe/Bucharest</timeZone>
    <locale xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:java="http://java.sun.com"
            xsi:type="java:java.lang.String">en_US</locale>
    <selectExpression></selectExpression>
</jsonDataAdapter>
```

And the output:

[image]

**Edit:** This should be regarded as a JasperReports v6.3.1 API solution only, until a newer version of JasperSoft Studio is released with proper support for header properties/parameters. Current latest version of JasperSoft Studio, v6.3.1 final, prevents reports with URL-based JSON data adapters from being previewed. Even [rebuilding JasperSoft Studio](http://community.jaspersoft.com/wiki/contributing-jaspersoft-studio-and-building-sources) from the 6.3.1 tag with the [fix](https://github.com/Jaspersoft/jasperreports/commit/b95edfe9c9103b0f7be812d2181fdea89fe84b90) for the bug that prevented it from working, does not seem to allow this solution to fully work with report based http properties, but only with fully configured JSON data adapter.

Comment: I appreciate your answer, I think It's little complicated, just for one report i must create an adapter for http request, The report i need to create is more than 400 report. I use netbeans as IDE , and netbeans not too user friendly to update the XML script, my report always broken if i update the XML script.

Comment: Well, this is just a newer out-of-the-box solution that people should know about. You pick whatever solution suits you best. If it helps in any way, you could also have a `URLParam`, similar to `CookieParam`, that wraps around the `net.sf.jasperreports.http.data.url` property so that you won't have to modify your adapter file to provide the URL.

Comment: Good idea, i will try it first. Another question, why i can use your method to access parent (**$.comp_name**) ?, why i can't find `jsonql` in ireport dropdown ?

Comment: Starting with version 5.5.0 iReport stopped from being the official design client for JasperReports. See the announcement [here](http://community.jaspersoft.com/project/ireport-designer). It got replaced with [JasperSoft Studio](http://community.jaspersoft.com/project/jaspersoft-studio). Most of JasperReports' features can still be accessed with iReport, but newer/more stable ones will require the Studio app. Features like the ones I've posted about(http properties and JSONQL) are part of the latest JasperReports public release and are still under development on the design client side.

Comment: Most new and existing major features of JasperReports can always be discovered  through the [JasperReports Sample Reference](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/sample.reference.html) page.

Comment: Jaspersoft Studio give me NPE error if i preview it with http json as adapter. I am searching over google and found this link http://community.jaspersoft.com/jasperreports-library/issues/8671 , jasper studio not solving the problem yet.

Comment: @yuda According to me this is a really great answer (new feature) and can be very useful for future users, I strongly advice you, even if in your own project use another solution, to consider also this when distributing bounty.

Comment: @yuda The error you mentioned has been fixed, but unfortunately there has been no new release for Studio since then.

Comment: @Narcis the big question is, how you can test it with jasper studio but i can't because if i click preview button always shows NPE error.

Comment: @PetterFriberg I am agree with you if i can test the code with jasper studio.

Comment: I admit I did not test it Studio. That's why I did not mention Studio it in the answer. I've worked directly in the [httpdataadapter](https://github.com/Jaspersoft/jasperreports/tree/jr-6-3-1/jasperreports/demo/samples/httpdataadapter) sample that uses the pure JasperReports API. Let me see if I can patch Studio with the fix for the NPE issue.

Comment: I've edited my answer with latest findings. It seems that rebuilding JasperSoft Studio 6.3.1 with the fix for NPE does not fully allow for this solution to work. The report-based http properties seem to be ignored and the only way to get it working is to have the adapter configured with all the headers and URL.